# How to return an array from a c# dll to php

Tags: c#, php, .net, com

I have the following c# class library:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace phptest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int getint()
        {
            return 17;
        }

        public string getstring()
        {
            return "yup";
        }

        public int doubleint(int x)
        {
            return x * 2;
        }

        public string doublestring(string s)
        {
            return s + s;
        }

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
        public int[] getintarray()
        {
            return new int[] { 1, 7, 9 };
        }
    }
}
```

and the following php script to test it:

```
$obj = new COM("phptest.Class1");
print $obj->getint();
print "\r\n" . $obj->getstring();
print "\r\n" . $obj->doublestring("dog") . "\r\n";
print $obj->doubleint(11);
$x = $obj->getintarray();
print_r($x);
```

It all works except for the `getintarray();`

The last line of the php script outputs: `variant Object`

`var_dump($x)` comes up with blank.

if I change the c# to return an array of objects instead:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
public object[] getintarray()
{
    return new object[] { 1, 7, 9 };
}
```

then `var_dump($x)` comes up with:

```
object(variant)#2 (0) {
}
```

How do I get at the values in the array passed back by the c# dll?

Is there something I need to do to the c# or the php or both?

I'll also be needing string arrays, so any help on that would be most welcome too.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Michael, I tried the following:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public int[] getintarray()
...
```

It has the same returns as when I had it returning an object array.

Also `count($x)` gives me the number of elements in the returned array (3 in this case)

I have tried accessing the elements in the following ways:

```
$x[0]          outputs "variant Object"
$x->value      outputs nothing
$x[0]->value   outputs nothing
$x->0          outputs nothing
```

var_dump($x[0]) gives me the same as var_dump($x)

Comment: Have you tried `UnmanagedType.LPArray`? That is a *c-style* array...

Comment: Have now - does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way to do it but see if you are able to get anything with this in Php.

```
foreach($x as $array){
    echo "Value ".$array. "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Does not work, result is `Value at 0 is Value at 1 is Value at 2 is Value at 3 is`

Comment: don't know why that works where other methods don't, but it does, so thank you

Comment: I have read some more on this, and it seems that PHP arrays are not actually arrays, but they are hash tables / linked lists.  This is why it is not simple to do.  See https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html for details.  In short, a lot of effort to replicate and I'm not going to bother :-)

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you just save the array in a temporary text document and then read it back in again?

I guess I would do so.

MfG BTM3000

Comment: yes and I could also pass the entire result back as a string and parse it in the php, but if I can avoid that, I would like to.